# Object Under Resistive Force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

An object of mass $m = 5.00 g$ is moving at constant velocity $v_0 = 3.10 m/s$. At $t = 0$ and 
$x = 1.50 m$, it is subjected to a resistive force $F_{res} = −mbv^2$ where $b = 0.520 m^{−1}$
is a constant. (Assume that the initial velocity is pointing in the positive direction.)

Express the velocity as a function of time. (Use the following as necessary: $m$, $b$, $t$, and $v_0$. Do not substitute numerical values; use variables only. Indicate the direction with the sign of your answer.)

---

An attempt at this solution started with stating

$a(t)=-bv^2$

Then integrating to find

$v(t) = -t(bv^2) + C$

@ $t=0$, $v=v_0$.

So, $C = v_0$

and then we end up with this:

$v(t) = -t(bv^2) + v_0$

I can't seem to solve for $v$ correctly, even when using the quadratic formula.

Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we see how you tried to solve for v?  For all we know, you could be going in the right direction, just making an algebra mistake or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

accroding to your attempt, how can $v(t)$ itself a function of $v$
Instead
$$a(t)=-bv^2$$
$$\frac{dv}{dt}=-bv^2$$
$$\frac{dv}{v^2}=-bdt$$
$$\int_{v_0}^v\frac{dv}{v^2}=-\int_0^tbdt$$
$$\frac{-1}v-\frac{-1}{v_0}=-b(t-0)$$
$$\frac{1}v=bt+\frac{1}{v_0}=\frac{btv_0+1}{v_0}$$
$$v=\frac{v_0}{1+bv_0t}$$